# Powershell script to create folder and copy file to remote server

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting, windows-scripting

I written a below PowerShell script to create a folder on remote computer if not exist and copy the file into the remote location, I am getting the below error can anyone help on this.

```
$serverlist = Get-Content "C:\serverlist.txt"
foreach ($server in $serverlist){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {

    $testpath = Test-Path "\\$server\D$\scripts"
        if($testpath -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Host "Path exist on $env:COMPUTERNAME, copying scirpt to the location"
            Copy-Item -Path \\hostx\copyshare\scirpts\IISLog.ps1 -Destination \\$server\D$\scripts -PassThru
        }
        else
        {
            #create a new folder on C drive
            Write-Host "Creating new folder...... "
            New-Item -Path \\$server\D$ -Name "scripts" -ItemType Directory
            sleep -Seconds 4
            Write-Host "Copying the script to destination...."
            Copy-Item -Path \\hostx\copyshare\scirpts\IISLog.ps1 -Destination \\$server\D$\scripts -Verbose
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
The path is not of a legal form.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\\D$\scripts:String) [New-Item], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
+ PSComputerName        : XXHOST


The network path was not found.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
+ PSComputerName        : XXHost
```

I have noticed after once the if loop is started the `$server` variable data is releasing not sure why this happened.

Comment: What happens if you change `New-Item -Path \\$server\D$ -Name "scripts" -ItemType Directory` for `New-Item -Path "\\$server\D$\scripts" -ItemType Directory` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I just tested in my lab, Script throwing the same error. I am unsure how computer name in $server is going null once it comes to if loop, This what i am suspecting based on the error.

Comment: Wait, this is actually my bad lol. Didn't see the `Invoke-Command` at the top, if you want to use a local variable in a remote scope you can use `$using:variableName` i.e.: `$using:server` in your case.

Comment: In addition, you don't really need `Invoke-Command` there.. but if you were still remoting to the host where you're gonna copy the remote file, you can for example just do `New-Item -Path "D:\scripts" -ItemType Directory` (you're already invoking the command on `$server` and the command can be invoked locally, hope it makes sense). If it sill doesn't make sense let me know and ill add the 2 examples on how to do what you need.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thank You, I need Invoke-Command in script, The actual script has three parts. This Check folder and copy file is first part of the script. 

I am confused to where to declare the {$using:server} in the script, Do i need declare in the beginning of the script block or in some where middle of the script ?

Answer (score 1):

So, as I said in my comment, you have 2 options to copy the script from a remote host to another remote host.

It is possible that the first option may give you a **double-hop** error, if that was the case you should be looking at [**`CredSSP`**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/) or **Service Principal Name / Kerberos Delegation**.

#### Option 1: With `Invoke-Command`

```
$serverlist = Get-Content "C:\serverlist.txt"

$scriptBlock = {
    # Since this is already happening on the scope of $server (remote host)
    # you don't really need to use a network path.
    # If you still want to use it, you can do, \\localhost\D$\scripts too.
    if(-not(Test-Path "D:\scripts"))
    {
        Write-Host "Creating new folder...... "
        New-Item -Path "D:\scripts" -ItemType Directory
    }

    sleep -Seconds 4
    Write-Host "Copying the script to destination...."
    # Not sure if "scirpts" is intended or a typo here
    Copy-Item -Path "\\hostx\copyshare\scirpts\IISLog.ps1" -Destination "D:\scripts\" -Verbose
}

foreach ($server in $serverlist)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock   
}
```

#### Option 2: Without `Invoke-Command`

```
$serverlist = Get-Content "C:\serverlist.txt"

foreach ($server in $serverlist)
{
    if(-not(Test-Path "\\$server\D$\scripts"))
    {
        Write-Host "Creating new folder...... "
        New-Item -Path "\\$server\D$\scripts" -ItemType Directory
    }

    sleep -Seconds 4
    Write-Host "Copying the script to destination...."
    Copy-Item -Path "\\hostx\copyshare\scirpts\IISLog.ps1" -Destination "\\$server\D$\scripts\" -Verbose
}
```

Now, to understand the `$using:`, or ***how to use local variables on remote hosts***, here is a link for [Example 9 of MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1#example-9--include-local-variables-in-a-command-run-on-a-remote-computer) which explains it really well.

You can also use `-ArgumentList` to pass the variables to the remote host, and then use the `$args` automatic variable or a `param(...)` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line \$server\D$\scripts with the following so that it expands correctly (your error code shows three backslashes)

```
"\\$server\D$\scripts"
```

I feel that this script could use a re-write all together - if you're invoking a command on a remote computer, you can reference that computers folder structure directly without using remote shares.

For example, use `"D:\scripts"` instead of `\\server1\D$\scripts`